# Chrome Extension: Context menu in URL field

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have made a simple extension to search for text on specific sites. I have the need to use text in the URL field. However the context menu does not show when right clicking in URL field.

Googling on this has yielded no results. I think it's strange if it's not possible but that might be the case. Hoping someone knows the trick.

Example of my code

```
function searchGoogle(info,tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({  
    url: "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + info.selectionText
  });
}

var contextMain = {
    "id": "mainMenu",
    "title": "Search",
    "contexts": ["selection"],
};

var contextGoogle = {
    "id": "subGoogle",
    "parentId": "mainMenu",
    "title": "Google",
    "contexts": ["selection"],
    onclick: searchGoogle
};

chrome.contextMenus.create(contextMain);
chrome.contextMenus.create(contextGoogle);
```

Comment: The address bar doesn't show items from extensions in its context menu. As you can see in https://crbug.com/234425 no one worked on implementing this feature during the last 6 years so I doubt it'll be implemented anytime soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question was answered by wOxxOm**

The address bar doesn't show items from extensions in its context menu. As you can see in crbug.com/234425 no one worked on implementing this feature during the last 6 years so I doubt it'll be implemented anytime soon. – wOxxOm